# Why is the sequence $u_m$ bounded in $H^1_0(\Omega)?$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I am studying a variational problem and in particular, the goal is to minimize  the following functional,
$$E_{\lambda}(u) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 - \lambda |u|^2 -\frac{1}{2^*}\int |u|^{2*}dx$$
where $u\in H^1_{0}(\Omega)$, $\lambda > 0$, $2^*=\frac{2n}{n-2}$ and $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 3.$ Then we can see that the differential $dE_{\lambda}(u)$ for the the test function $u$ itself
$$
\langle dE_{\lambda}(u),u \rangle =\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 - \lambda |u|^2-|u|^{2^*} dx..
$$
Given this the statement I am trying to understand the proof of the following claim:

**Claim.**
Let $u_m$ be a sequence of functions in the space $H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that $E_{\lambda}(u_m)\leq c$ uniformly and $dE_{\lambda}(u_m)\to 0$ as $m\to \infty$ strongly in  $H^{-1}(\Omega).$ Then $u_m$ is bounded.

**Attempt.** Th author starts by observing that,
$$
2E_{\lambda}(u_m)-\langle dE_{\lambda}(u_m), u_m\rangle \leq 2c+(1+||u_m||_{H^1_0(\Omega)})o(1)
$$
where $o(1)\to 0$ as $m\to \infty.$ I don't understand why this claim holds. The $2c$ upper bound is obvious, however, the upper-bound on the inner product is not clear to me. Any comments/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
|-\langle dE_{\lambda}(u_m), u_m\rangle|
\leq \|dE_{\lambda}(u_m)\| \cdot \|u_m\|
\leq (1+\|u_m\| )\|dE_{\lambda}(u_m)\|
= (1+\|u_m\| ) o(1),
$$
where the last inequality is because of $dE_{\lambda}(u_m)\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I should have gone to bed earlier